# SPARQL Results in multiple Languages

Tags: database, sparql, multilingual

I have a quite simple query to find all the museums (museum, abstract) that have at least 1 artwork.

It works fine.

I would like to have the Abstract in various languages... how can i solve it?

Here the very simple query:

```
SELECT  ?museum ?abstract   WHERE {  
?museum <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract. 
?museum a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Museum>.
?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ?museum.
}
```

Now the result is :

NameX -- Description in Italian

i would like to have:

NameX -- Description in Italian -- Decription in English -- Decription in french -- Decription in deutsch

Thanks all

Maurizio

Comment: Please add some information about the schemas to your question to allow others to help you with the query syntax...

Comment: ok, i use the italian endpoint: http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: Using the english dbpedia endpoint is it possible?

Comment: If i run the query :                                              SELECT  ?museum ?abstract   WHERE {  
?museum <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract. 
?museum a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Museum>.
}
in the http://dbpedia.org/sparql endpoint

it responses with a multilanguage output for every row...

i would like to have it in the same row, possibly selecting the languages viewed...

Answer (score 1):

I think you will end up defining every bit of code separately. This is my attempt:

```
SELECT  ?museum ?EnglishAbstract ?ItalianAbstract ?FrenchAbstract
WHERE { 
    ?museum dbpedia-owl:abstract ?EnglishAbstract. 
    ?museum a dbpedia-owl:Museum.
    ?artwork dbpedia-owl:location ?museum.
filter(lang(?EnglishAbstract)='en')

optional{
    ?museum dbpedia-owl:abstract ?ItalianAbstract. 
    ?museum a dbpedia-owl:Museum.
    ?artwork dbpedia-owl:location ?museum.
filter(lang(?ItalianAbstract)='it')
}

optional{
    ?museum dbpedia-owl:abstract ?FrenchAbstract. 
    ?museum a dbpedia-owl:Museum.
    ?artwork dbpedia-owl:location ?museum.
filter(lang(?FrenchAbstract)='fr')
}
}
```

Comment: Ok that's a incredibly good start, but i would like to have each result (each for every language i choose) in the same row for a museum: For example Name_of_museum - description_ita - description_eng - description_deu ...

Comment: I don't think there is a way apart from actually specifying the language of every abstract separately.

Comment: Ok, that's it. I supposed to specify that separately. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok i've seen a particularity:

your query can be resolved only beacause on the international endpoint they have installed also the "canonized" dataset (that's not documentated).

i'm looking for a most general solution, using the "owl:sameAs"

i made a "not so good but useful to explicate" query:

SELECT ?obj WHERE { dbpedia:Moma (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs) ?obj }

Ok, i would like fo find with the sameAs not only the Moma museum, but all the museums with the abstract for each in the same row...

Comment: I'm not getting what is exactly the problem. You should edit your question with the new problem and then maybe I'll understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` statement.

```
SELECT  ?museum ?abstract
WHERE {  
    ?museum <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract. 
    ?museum a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Museum>.
    ?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ?museum.

    filter(lang(?abstract) in ('en', 'it', 'fr'))
}
```